# how to explode mysql table data in php

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql table table data, one column has multiple value like this,

```
code  name
1,2,3 a
4     b
```

My desired output will be

```
code name
1    a
2    a
3    a
4    b
```

Here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM hsc_sub group by sub_name order by sub_code";
$res = app_db_query($app,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  //enter code here
  $subj[] = $row;
  $subj[] = explode(",",$row['sub_code']);
}
```

Comment: I'd start with that first sentence... ***normalize*** your database into multiple tables and rows, don't store comma separated values in one field!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the ForEach Loop, we can achieve your requirement.

```
$subCode[];
$name[];


echo("Code");
echo("\t");
echo("Name");
echo("\n");

$sql="SELECT * FROM hsc_sub group by sub_name order by sub_code";
$res = app_db_query($app,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $nm = $row['sub_name']
  $sub[] = explode(",",$row['sub_code']);
  foreach($sub as $item)
  {
    $name.push($nm);
    $subCode.push($item);

    echo($item);
    echo("\t");
    echo($nm);
    echo("\n");
  }
}
```